# Accessing a specific object by name/number?

Tags: php

I'm returning some data, and testing my return by using `var_dump($this);`. It returns the following:

```
object(ReportingService)#333 (2) {
  ["_arrErrors"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["nameWS"]=>
  string(14) "reportingstuff"
}
{"arrMessages":[{"_strMessage":"Example.","_strType":"valid","_strModule":null}],"arrContent":{"isSuccess":"1","statistics":"<div id=\"entities\">
```

What I am trying to do is to access the `nameWS` property of the object, but cannot seem to do so.

What I've tried:

```
var_dump($this[0]->nameWS);
```

Comment: Is the data you have Json or an array?

Comment: JSON, received from a web service response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following:

```
$this->nameWS;
```

You find more information in the manual [Setting and Getting Object Properties](http://www.php.net/manual/en/sdo.sample.getset.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can access it via:

```
$this->nameWS;
```

The zero you were using is for the array in "_arrErrors", so you don't need that.

```
echo $this->nameWS;
```

will output:

```
reportingstuff
```